# Difference between ManagedExecutorService and ManagedThreadFactory in Java EE

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Our current legacy web-app creates threads in it not managed by Application Server Containers. I have to modify it with JavaEE standards for multi-threading.

My web-app works fine on Tomcat but fails on Websphere.

Error on Websphere :

```
... ... Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names.
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwExceptionIfDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:534) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:564) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:485) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
```

In order to resolve this issue, I am referring [Concurrency Utilities in Java EE](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/concurrency-utilities002.html). I found similar kind of description and example for [ManagedExecutorService](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) and [ManagedThreadFactory](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedThreadFactory.html).

> - ManagedExecutorService: A managed executor service is used by applications to execute submitted tasks asynchronously. Tasks are
>   executed on threads that are started and managed by the container. The
>   context of the container is propagated to the thread executing the
>   task.
> - ManagedThreadFactory: A managed thread factory is used by applications to create managed threads. The threads are started and
>   managed by the container. The context of the container is propagated
>   to the thread executing the task. This object can also be used to
>   provide custom factories for specific use cases (with custom Threads)
>   and, for example, set specific/proprietary properties to these
>   objects.

Which one is preferred in which condition and why ?

Comment: kindly put comment why negative rating ? so, i can improve next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved issue by using ManagedExecutorService.

ExecutorService framework indeed has more ways to deal threads while ManagedThreadFactory can only call newThread() method.

Websphere issue can be resolved by using ManagedExecutorService or ManagedThreadFactory. Both works. But for further thread processing, ManagedExecutorService turns out lot better.

Now, this solution causes same web-app to fail on Tomcat. JNDI naming exception. As per my R&D, container based concurrency is supported in TomEE server not in Tomcat so we have to use routing mechanism to switch between code as per underlying application server.